# Deleting HTML Elements in JavaScript to avoid memory leaks

Tags: javascript, html, memory-management

I recently got into javascript, and my html coding skills are somewhat lacking. That being said, I've run into a few funny things that you can find in javascript. Because of the close use of javascript and html I'm afraid I've created a memory leak.

In this instance I wanted to create my own custom javascript alert style/confirm box. I wound up with effectively creating an html overlay through javascript. After the selection has been made, I remove that overlay.

```js
    var output;
    var createPromotionBox = function () {
        var choice = '';
        var b = document.getElementById('button-container');
        var box = document.createElement('div');
        box.setAttribute('id', 'alert-box');
        box.setAttribute('class','alert');
        b.appendChild(box);
        var text = document.createElement('div');
        text.setAttribute('class','alert-content');
        text.setAttribute('id', 'alert-text');
        text.innerHTML = 'Promote your pawn!<br>';
        box.appendChild(text);

        var arr = ['Q', 'N', 'R', 'B'];
        for(var i in arr) (function(i){
            var btn = document.createElement('button');
            btn.setAttribute('class','promotion-button');
            btn.setAttribute('id',arr[i]+'btn');
            btn.innerHTML = arr[i];
            btn.onclick = function () {
                output = arr[i];
                deletePromotionBox();
            };
            text.appendChild(btn);
        })(i);
    };

    var deletePromotionBox = function () {
        var arr = ['Q', 'N', 'R', 'B'];
        for(var i in arr) {
            removeElement(arr[i]+'btn');
        }
        removeElement('alert-text');
        removeElement('alert-box');
    };

    var removeElement = function (elementId) {
        var e = document.getElementById(elementId);
        e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
    };
    document.getElementById('btn').onclick = createPromotionBox;
```

```html
    <html>
    <body > Amazing code works! <br><br>
    <div class="button-box" id="button-container" style="width: 600px">
    <button id="btn">Click Me!</button>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Do I have a leak when I created `b`, `box`, `text`, and the `btn`'s? I removed the html elements but the variable references are now orphaned from their elements.

Also I think I read somewhere that I should not use `remove()`. Is there another way I should be doing this?

Comment: Those `var`s stop existing once the function finishes. So no, no memory leak. (Also note that your question title doesn't match your actual question)

Comment: What do you exactly mean with a memory leak? Make sure to use local variables in your JavaScript functions if you don't want the variables to be accessible from outside the function, or inside the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are algorithms used for garbage collection by garbage-collectors. Javascript uses the algorithm called **Mark and Sweep algorithm** in which every reachable object are preserved and unreachable object are cleared from the memory.

There are two stages for this algorithm.

**1. Mark**

The first stage is the mark stage which does a tree traversal of the entire **root set** and marks each object that is pointed to by a root as being **in-use**. All objects that those objects point to, and so on, are marked as well, so that every object that is reachable via the root set is marked.

**2. Sweep**

All memory is scanned from start to finish, examining all free or used blocks; those not marked as being 'in-use' are not reachable by any roots, and their memory is freed. For objects which were marked in-use, the in-use flag is cleared, preparing for the next cycle.

[image]

Also see :

[Tracing Garbage Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection)

[Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/)

In your case, `Do I have a leak when I created b, box, text, and the btn's?` No, because when you remove a traceable path for those object by using `removeChild` there are no other variables referring to those objects. So garbage collector freed up those objects.

Answer (score 4):

This should not create a memory leak.

If you remove the elements and the references to are out of scope then the garbage collector should clean them up using the mark and sweep algorithm.

You could always check in Chrome dev tools using the memory profiling tool see 
[DevTools memory leak problems](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/) for more info on this