# Test unmounting with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer

I am confused by when/how a queried element get updated. For example:

I have a button that counts up. And when it counts to 3, it disappears.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      {count < 3 && (
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'm testing it like so:

```
test("Counter counts up and disappears", () => {
  const { queryByText } = render(<App" />);

  const button = queryByText("0");
  expect(button.textContent).toEqual("0");

  fireEvent.click(button);
  expect(button.textContent).toEqual("1");

  fireEvent.click(button);
  expect(button.textContent).toEqual("2");

  fireEvent.click(button);
  expect(button).toBe(null);
});
```

The test failes with the following error:

```
expect(received).toBe(expected)

Expected value to be (using ===):
  null
Received:
  <button>2</button>
```

Why does the button element knows its text content has changed? We didn't need to run `queryByText("1")` and `queryByText("2")` after each click.

And why it doesn't know that the button has been unmounted after the last click? And we do need to do `queryByText("3")` if we want to check that it is indeed null.

Here's the code sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-testing-library-demo-76zhi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **guess** it's about how `react-dom` and `jsdom`(which used by testing too) works.

(Please correct me or let me know if guessing is unacceptable! I will remove this. )

1. Button type return by `queryByText` is [HtmlElment](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/blob/master/typings/queries.d.ts#L37)
2. `react` or `react-dom` is just minimize the task for dom manipulation, eventually `jsdom` would still do the text changing and button removing works.
3. Since the testing tool is using `jsdom`, I check the `removeChild` part of code, and believe [they are following W3C specification](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/75a921eab52c239b2468e08be9f547f46c7f86bd/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/Node-impl.js#L901). I assume in the level of dom manipulation, `jsdom` would works like browsers. Thus I simulated your code like this:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const btnContainer = document.getElementById('btnContainer');

btn.textContent = '1';
console.log('btn after click 1: ' + btn);
btn.textContent = '2';
console.log('btn after click 2: ' + btn);
btnContainer.removeChild(btn);
console.log('btn after removed: '+  btn);
```

```html
<div id='btnContainer'><button id='btn'>0<button></div>
```

4. As you can see, after removing from `div`, the `btn` variable is still `[object HTMLButtonElement]`
   Maybe It's similar to use `splice` to an array which contained a defined object, the initial obj still remains the same?

```js
const obj = { 'a': 1};
const arr = [obj];
arr[0]['a'] = 2;
arr.splice(0, -1);
console.log(obj)
```

---

Therefore, I think it's more about [how garbage collection works in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49147182/deleting-html-elements-in-javascript-to-avoid-memory-leaks).

In addition, maybe not to reuse the query result, and always query again in this situation, the result will be more expectable.

---

P.S. I found there is a method call [`toBeInTheDocument`](https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance#nottobeinthedocument)!

Comment: To add to this answer, definitely, it's better to perform a new query every time and to use `toBeInTheDocument`.